# Can anyone validate this set proof: If $A ⊆ \overline B$ for some sets A and B, does it imply that $B ⊆ \overline A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

By definition, the complement of a set, $\forall a \in A, \nexists a: a \in B$

Similarly $\forall b \in B, \nexists b: A$

This implies that B must contain some or all of the elements that are not contained in A.

So, $B\subseteq \overline A$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to MSE.

I see what you’re going for, but it’s better to write $A \subset \overline{B}$ as $\forall a \in A, a \notin B$.

Now fix some $b \in B$, and we want to show $b \in \overline{A}$, i.e. $b \notin A$. Proceeding by contradiction, what would be the case if $b \in A$?

Comment: if  $b \in A$ since $A \subseteq \overline B$ this must be a contradiciton as $b \notin \overline B$

Comment: Exactly, that’s your proof

Comment: Thanks for your help!